# Are there any project tracking tools that provide code change reports for clients and managers?

Tags: svn, controls, version, revision

Are there any good revision control tools that are easy to set up and accessible through multiple platforms (including iOS) for project status tracking by clients and managers?

Sometimes I make huge amendments to my code, yet it looks the same on the surface - which can be mistaken by client or managers as no changes were made.

I work mostly on PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) - A fantastic environment to work in that integrates with Kiln which is backed by Mercurial.
2. [SmartBear DevComplete](http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/devcomplete/) Looks good but I never used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found the [Trac timeline](http://trac.edgewall.org/timeline) a nice way of illustrating progress e.g. in a [subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion) repository.

It's Python based, though.

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/activity) is Ruby based and offers a very similar view.

Answer (score 1):

[FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) is pretty good and a starter license is very cheap.  It's worth trying, but I don't know how it might look on an iPhone for example.